# Handling 120000+ records in cshtml view in Tabular format

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have an MVC application. i am trying to fecth all the records from any table and display i to the user. The code is working fine except for one table where it has 120000+ records. the server api is returning the data in quick time, but when i try to loop through rows and columns of data tables, i am getting out of memroy excpetion. suggest me the best way to do this.

Comment: Using paging to return just a subset of the records (a user cannoy possibly absorb 120K records in one view - [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Comment: 120000 records are too much for any real human users ! Use paging to show a subset of data.

Comment: this is a requirement of the application. Also paging will create more round trips to server and in some cases, the tables in db might not contain any unique key or it might be not known

Answer (score 0):

there is a tag in web.config to increase the maximum request length
it will resolve the problem

```
      <system.web>
     <httpRuntime executionTimeout="100000" maxRequestLength="214748364" />
      </system.web>
```

Comment: actually, i am getting the data from database in quick time , the problem i am facing is iterating through the datatables in my View and creating the html table.

Comment: so in that if the data is coming properly then you need to call a jquery ajaxfunction. if you did this then your page will load quickly and after that your jquery ajax function will fire that loads all data.